# Compiling GCC on Catalina

Tags: terminal, xcode

I am trying to compile GCC9 on macOS Catalina. The closest tutorial I've found is [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/) one.

The tutorial states:

```
In order to build GCC install the required header files in the old location:

1 cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
2 open .
```

Command 1 doesn't work because my file structure is as follows:

```
 - Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode
 - Users/user/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices
 - /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
- /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/
```

As can be seen, the `Library/Developer` path associated with my user has no `CommandlineTools`, while that directly on `Macintosh HD` does.

Should I run the above commands from root `/`? Or should the `CommandLineTools` also be available directly to my user?